# Not an integer when verifying a bank account

Tags: balanced-payments

When trying to verify a bank account, I get a 'Invalid field [amount_1] - "0.44" is not an integer'

However, your docs specifies that amounts are always inferior to $1 so I'm not really sure how to deal with this situation

PS : verifying bank accounts on your Dashboard works fine, and I'm using API v1.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the variable to integer if doesn't work the track your code if haven't assign it to a double or decimal

Comment: I mean if it's always < 1 it's always gonna be converted to 0 (with a parseInt for instance) so that won't work

Answer (score 0):

Ok basically you need to input the cents as integer (as said on #balanced channel)